# Cisco APIC routing protocol status via CLI?

Tags: cisco

ACI Path

```
Tenants > Networking > External Routed Networks >
```

In the area with the routing protocol check boxes, there are a few options such as BGP, OSPF, and EIGRP.

In this image, BGP and OSPF have been enabled.

What is the equivalent CLI command for this?

I need to find out what kind of protocols been enabled there via SSH.

[image]

Source image: https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/5.6.3/fortigate-connector-cisco-aci-deployment-package/481593/bgp

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Login to APIC CLI and execute:

```
APIC1# show run leaf 101 router eigrp default
# Command: show running-config leaf 101 router eigrp default
# Time: Wed Apr  1 16:52:53 2020
  leaf 101
    router eigrp default
      vrf member tenant EXP vrf Default_VRF
        autonomous-system 65001 l3out _EXP_L3Out
        exit
      exit
```

Where leaf **101** it's an leaf id number. You can find yours by running `APIC# acidiag fnvread`. Each leaf has its own routing configuration. So you should run thru all leafs youre interested in.

**EXP** - tenant name, **Default_VRF** - VRF (context) name, **_EXP_L3Out** - name of the L3Out object.

The idea for BGP/OSPF is the same - just replace **eigrp** with respective protocol name.

Comment: `APIC# acidiag fnvread
_exec_legacy_cmd:9: permission denied: /controller/sbin/acidiag
APIC#
`

Comment: As a workaround run this from APIC CLI to get leaf IDs from MIT: `APIC-1# moquery -c fabricNode -f 'fabric.Node.role=="leaf"' | egrep ^id`